# Not wanted to print query results in psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2

Hi so I've been working on this code for a while and I don't want my select query to print into my console the results of that same query.
I'm building an app that, when the user logs in, it (the app) fetches into a postgresql table the credentials and if those in the database are the same of the ones given by the user it lets to log in.
The only problem is that every time it searches for the credentials it prints them into the consolle and i don't know why. Can you help me?

Here is the code

```
class LoginPage(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)
    valid = False

    def log_into_account(self, email, password, valid):
        with ps.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(f'''SELECT email, password from "'{email}'" WHERE id = 1''')
                    credentials = cur.fetchone()
                    if self.password.text == credentials(1):
                        self.valid = True
                    else:
                        self.valid = False
                except:
                    invalid_login_info()
                    self.valid = False
                    return self.valid

    def login(self):
        print(self.email.text, self.email.text)
        if self.email.text != '' or self.email.text != '':
            self.log_into_account(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.valid)
            return self.valid
        else:
            self.valid = False
            invalid_login_info()
            return self.valid

        self.email.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''
```

And if it finds the user, it always prints his credentials in the consolle like this

```
massimo massimo
# Where the first one is the username and the second is the password
```

I think I gave you all the necessary, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that's not credentials.  That's the user's email, which you print twice as the first line of `login`.  That's the only `print` statement in this entire code.  Should have been pretty easy to find.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I didn't find it because it was very late in the night yesterday here in Italy and I was really tired. Thank you anyway!